# ReactNative/Flex: how to arrange two components horizontal?

Tags: react-native, reactjs, jsx

How to arrange 2 Image-Components next to another in the same row with flex?

Like this:

|| (image 1) || (image 2) ||

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`flexDirection: 'row'` is your friend

Comment: Add an example of hot to use this style to improve the answer.

Answer (score 7):

I think something like this...

```
<View style={{flexDirection:'row', alignItems:'center', justifyContent:'center'}}>
  <Image source... />
  <Image source... />
</View>
```

Now depending on how do you want the spaced horizontally you can use different [justifyContent](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/j/justify-content/)

Answer (score 0):

First we set the flex direction to row, this will arrange the children horizontally. In order to center the component horizontally we use the alignItems property, then we use justifyContent to vertically center the component.
Try like this :

```css
var styles = StyleSheet.create({
    firstComponent:{
        flexDirection:'row'    
    },
    childrens:{     
        width: 120,       
        color:'#fff',
        alignItems:'center'
    }
});
```